# How does threading or Multiprocessing work with recursions?

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, scalability, multiprocessing

**Background**

I'm a bit new to developing and had a general python/programming question.  If you have a method that is a recursion, what is involved to enabling multiple threads or multiprocessing?  I've done some light reading and a few examples but they seem to be applying the syntax for new code(and not very cpu intensive tasks), I'm more wondering how do I re-design existing code to do this?

Say I have something thats cpu intensive(basically keeps adding to itself until limit is hit):

```
def adderExample(sum, number):
    if sum > 1000:
        print 'sum is larger than 10. Stoping'
    else:
        sum = sum + number
        print sum
        number = number + 1
        adderExample(sum, number)


adderExample(0,0)
```

**Question(s)/Though process**

How would I approach this to make it run faster assuming I have multiple cores available(I want it to eventually want it span machines but I think thats a sperate issue with hadoop so I'll keep this example to only one system with multiple cpu's)? It seems threading it isn't the best choice(because of the time it takes to spawn new threads), if thats true should I only focus on multiprocessing? If so, can recursions be split to different cpu's(vai queues I assume and then rejoin after its done)?  Can I create multiple threads for each process than split those processes over multiple cpu's?  Lastly, is recursion depth limits an overall limit or is it based on threads/proceses, if so does multiprocessing/threading get around it?

Another question(related) how do those guys trying to codes(rsa, wireless keys,etc) via brute force overcome this problem?  I assume they are scaling their mathematical processes over multiple cpu somehow. This or any example to build my understanding would be great.

Any tips/suggestions would be great

Thanks!

Comment: in general, processes take more time and overhead to spawn than threads. Threads use the same memory space as the starting program. Processes must create their new memory overhead. With threading, you're also able to easily incorporate the sharing of information structures without copying them, there is no way to easily do that with multiple processes without going to the OS' (or other) based 'shared memory' IPC implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a loop wouldn't benefit much at all from threading. Consider that you're doing a series of additions, whose intermediate values depend on the previous iterations. This can't be parallelized, because the threads would be stomping on each other's values and overwriting things. You can lock the data so only one thread works on it at a time, but then you lose any benefit of having multiple threads working on that data.

Threads work best when they have independent data sets. e.g. a graphics renderer is a perfect example. Each thread renders a subset of the larger image - they may share common data sources for texture/vertex/color/etc... data, but each thread has its own little section of the total image to work one, and doesn't touch other areas of the image. Whatever thread #1 does on its little section of pixels won't affect what thread #2 is doing elsewhere in the image.

For your related question, password cracking is another example where threading/multiprocessing makes sense. Each thread goes off on its own testing multiple possible passwords against one common "to be cracked" list. What one thread is doing doesn't affect any of the other cracker threads, unless you get a match, which may mean all threads abort since the job is "done".

Once threads become interdependent on each other, you lose a lot of the benefits of having multiple threads. They'll spend more time waiting for the other to finish than they'll spend on doing actual work. Of course, this doesn't say you should never use threads. Sometimes it does makes sense to have multiple threads, even if they are interdependent. E.g. a graphics thread + sound effects thread + action processor thread + A.I. calculations thread, etc... in a game. each one is nominally dependent on each other, but while the sound thread is busy generating the bang+ricochet audio for the gun the player just shot, the a.i. thread is off calculating what the game's mobs are doing, the graphics thread is drawing some clouds in the background, etc...

Comment: I think I understand a bit more, Thank you Marc.  Just to understand further, I understand a password cracker using a dictionary and queuing it up, but what if the cracker generating their own passwords(not dictionary based forexample a,b, c, ...aa, ab,ac,etc).  Is my understanding correct if I think they cannot multiprocess the generation of the combo's(but can multiprocess actually trying to use  the password because the combo's are being put in a queue)?

Comment: You can parallelize the process, **IF** you can split the task up. e.g. for a list of numeric sequential passwords (1,2,3,4,5,etc...) you can split it up in 2 threads (one doing evens, one doing odds), etc... as long as you can make each thread have its own independent portion of the overall list, then no problem. But if you've got 5 threads, but splitting the workload into only 4 pieces, then you're going to waste some time duplicating work.

Answer (score 1):

Threading kinda sorta implies multiple stacks, recursion single stacks. That said, if you get to the recurse-left, recurse-right part and decide to spawn threads for the sub-problems if the current count of threads is "low" and do straight recursion otherwise you can combine the concepts.

But regular Python is not a good language for this pattern. Python threads all run on the same interpreter hardware thread, so you  won't actually pick up any multiprocessing goodness.

Answer (score 0):

Phunctor is correct that the threading library is a poor choice for parallelizing this type of problem, due to the "Global Interpreter Lock" that prevents multiple threads from executing Python code in parallel.

Where the threading library can be highly useful, though, is when each thread's code spends a lot of time waiting for I/O to happen.  So, for example, if you're implementing a server that has to hit the disk or wait on a network response, servicing a request in each thread can be very efficient, since the threading library can favor the ones that are not waiting on I/O and thus maximize use of the Python interpreter.  (In a single thread, you'd have to use a tight loop checking the statuses of your I/O requests, which would tend to be wasteful as load got high.)